# error while i try to reach a web service

Tags: windows-phone-7, webservice-client

im trying to reach via VS2010 a web service at this address 
http://myluckyday.fr/orange/actus.php
and i got this error message :

The document at the url http://myluckyday.fr/orange/actus.php was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be  and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL http://myluckyday.fr/orange/actus.php could not be found.'.
  - The document format is not recognized.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 45).'.
  -  was not expected.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://myluckyday.fr/orange/actus.php'.
The content type application/xml of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: 'Indemnit� de rupture c...Comment enregistrer l'indemn...http://www.pro.orange.fr/ImgEntrepreneurActu/110918_1295942777_rupture-contrat-illus-e.jpghttp://www.myluckyday.fr/orange/actus.php?id=205EIRL : les porteurs de...Alors que le nouveau statut ...http://www.pro.orange.fr/ImgEntrepreneurActu/110870_1295860277_protection-patrimoine-06-e.jpghttp://www.myluckyday.fr/orange/actus.php?id=201D�claration d'emploi d...� compter de l'ann�e prochai...http://www.pro.orange.fr/ImgEntrepreneurActu/110916_1295886094_handicap-couloir-e.jpghttp://www.myluckyday.fr/orange/actus.php?id=207Espace fumeurs : un no...Les affichettes signalant le...http://www.pr'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

anyone got an idea how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are trying to add that URL as a service reference, but the URL is for an RSS feed, not for a web service. If you're trying to build an RSS reader for Windows Phone 7, then you might find this article useful: http://cespage.com/silverlight/wp7tut17.html

Comment: hi derek,ty for ur reply, i m gonna try ur link which seems very helpful but my worksmate android and Ios use this link like this. and i have read many tutorial where they says u can add an url in the "service reference"

Comment: Yes you can add a service reference to an actual web service, but the URL that you provided is not a web service, it's an RSS feed.